# Can someone explain to me how $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{n}{(n+k)(n+k+1)}=\frac{n}{n+1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation, telescopic-series

I am stuck here. It looks like some sort of a binomial coefficient but I just can't figure out how wolfram alpha produces this exact solution:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{n}{(n+k)(n+k+1)}=\frac{n}{n+1}$$

Comment: Why leave uncancelled $n$s on both sides?

Comment: Partial fractions & telescope sum.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Because I only have the left side. Cancelling $n$ would be assuming the solution already

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I have tried partial fractions but I didn't see thetelescope sum. I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: @qmd: Nope, it wouldn't. Nothing prevents you from first proving it without the $n$s, and then multiplying both sides by $n$ (after straightforward convergence considerations have been made).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the telescoping sum: $$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{n}{(n+k)(n+k+1)}=n\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n+k}-\frac{1}{n+k+1}\right)=$$
$$=n\lim_{k\rightarrow+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+k+1}\right)=\frac{n}{n+1}$$

Comment: That was so obvious I don't know why I didn't think of that. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @qmd You are welcome!